# javascript redirect progress incrementor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I have a page attached called welcome.

basically this page will be redirected to another page via javascript 
the page it will be redirected to could take 1-2 minutes to respond and therefore i need the % on the page incremented as we wait (as per the js below)

the problem i currently have is that once we request to redirect the page the incrementation does not continue

here is the html :

```
  <p>We are currently processing your application... please be patient...</p><br/>
        <center><img src="site/images/ajax-loader.gif">
        <br/><br/>
        <h2><span id='perouter'><span id="per">0</span>% complete</span>            </h2>


        <input type="hidden" name="" id="redirectdelay" value="2000">
         <!-- the redirect delay here will be taken from the config table -->
        <input type="hidden" name="" id="redirecturl" value="http://cmsdude.com/delay/delay.php?seconds=30">
         <!-- the redirect url here will be the welcome page -->
```

and the javascript :

```
<script>



function test(){
      //alert('ll');
}



function doTheUpdate(perc){
perc=perc+5;


if(perc<100){
setTimeout(function() {
doTheUpdate(perc);
}, document.getElementById("redirectdelay").value);

}else{
document.getElementById("perouter").innerHTML='Almost there - Please wait 1 minute...';
}

}
function updatePer(perc){

document.getElementById("per").innerHTML=perc;
if(perc<4){
setTimeout(function()
            { test(); }
     , 4000);

}
perc=perc+5;




if(perc<100){
setTimeout(function() {
doTheUpdate(perc);
}, document.getElementById("redirectdelay").value);

}else{
document.getElementById("perouter").innerHTML='Almost there - Please wait 1 minute...';
}
window.location.href = document.getElementById("redirecturl").value;


}

 updatePer(1);
</script>
```

any help appreciated ??

Comment: if you redirect to other page, you lost the percentage, you can pass the perc value like query string: ?perc=57 and after load and continuos...

Comment: thanks for suggestion but no i need to wait for the external link to come back with an answer to my call